# Why does this function return the same value regardless of input?

Tags: objective-c

I have a method that formats a date string. I've encountered an issue where it returns only the formatted version of the first NSString I pass to it..

Code:

```
  self.lastUpdatedLabel.text  =   [self convertTime:lastupdated];
  self.expiryDate.text        =   [self convertTime:expiryDate];
```

Method

```
- (NSString *)convertTime:(NSString *)date{

    NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [timeFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm - dd/MM/yyyy"];
    [timeFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
    date = [timeFormatter stringFromDate:[[NSDate alloc]init] ];
    return date;
}
```

Both lastUpdatedLabel and expiry date are set to the value of expiryDate. Surely the method runs every time it is called, producing a different output as the input is different

Comment: `[timeFormatter stringFromDate:[[NSDate alloc]init] ];` You are transforming the same Data (at some milliseconds-ish) into NSString.  So they are the same (since the minimum diff you use is minutes). There should be case where the minute should differs (since there are small milliseconds diffs).

Comment: oh... So that's just returning current time?

Comment: Print `[[NSDate alloc] init]`, because that's the date you are converting. In fact if `lastupdated` is really a NSString, you might want to give its value, because your code is missing steps. It won't work.

Comment: Does `convertTime` use the `date` input?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to update your code to use your argument, `date`.

As people have mentioned in comments, you are using the current time, `[[NSDate alloc] init]` instead of the `date` that was passed in.

If `lastUpdated` and `expiryDate` are NSDates, then this will work.

```
- (NSString *)convertTime:(NSDate *)date{

    NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [timeFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm - dd/MM/yyyy"];
    [timeFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]]; 
    return [timeFormatter stringFromDate:date];
}
```

If `lastUpdated` and `expiryDate` are NSStrings, which is what it looks like you have, then you need to convert your NSStrings to NSDates, using an NSDateFormatter that understands the format of the NSString that you have ... and then pass that NSDate to the code above to create a properly formatted string as output.